# I am getting error when trying to refresh the access token

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, quickbooks, refresh-token

When the access token expires I am using a command following to this in order to get a new one:

```
    curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H 
    "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic THE CODE"  -H 
    "Cache-Control: no-cache" -X POST  
    https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer?
    grant_type=authorization_code&refresh_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Instead of getting new access token I am getting this error:

```
    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 27
    Connection: keep-alive
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5
    Server: nginx
    Date: Sat, 19 Aug 2017 11:48:55 GMT
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
    intuit_tid: a406d5cd-3438-d1b2-37fc-d781c9f23ac4
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
    Pragma: no-cache

    {"error":"invalid_request"}
```

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The `grant_type` should be `refresh_token`, not `authorization_code`